# How to always get data from database, not cache

Tags: entity-framework

I have a windows form application that is getting data through the Entity Framework.

When two instances of the app are open, if you change data in one, it is not changed in the other, even if the second queries again for the data.  In other words, it seems like it is getting data from a cache, instead of directly from the database.

So is there a setting to tell EF to always fetch data from the Db?

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specify `MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;`

```
result.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

more on it is here

http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2010/02/16/setting-entity-framework-mergeoptions-what-works-what-doesn-t.aspx

you van also try

```
ObjectContext.Refresh
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx